# Unable to receive email notification from GCP stackdriver monitoring when using DL?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, notifications, monitoring, google-cloud-stackdriver

I have setup a metric which will look for any exceptional error in my GCP cloud function, Then I have created a alerting policy and using notification channel as 'Email'. The problem here is when I use my own personnel email address, I get email notification on exceptional error from . But when I use DL address of my team as email notification channel it does not sent any email notification even there is an exceptional error in my cloud function.

Anyone has any resolution on this issue ?

Thank you in advance !!

Answer (score 5):

> If you create an alerting policy and select Email in the Notifications section, then enter your email address. If you use a group email address, then configure the group to accept mail from alerts@stackdriver.com.

see: https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/support/notification-options

Here's how you can configure groups to receive emails from stackdriver. See: support.google.com/a/answer/167097 Outside this domain - access to groups > Group owners can allow incoming email from outside this domain

Comment: We have not received any verification email from stackdriver. Also I referred this link  https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/support/notification-options, but didn't understand from where exactly we need to configure the group to accept mail from alerts@stackdriver.com. Can you please guide me on this as well.

Comment: ok, looks like it's a google groups permission issue. You need to configure groups to receive emails from stackdriver. See: https://support.google.com/a/answer/167097 Outside this domain - access to groups > Group owners can allow incoming email from outside this domain